# Is there a reason that mocha does not support describes within it functions?

Tags: mocha.js, protractor

using mocha+protractor... example... you have a test spec to go hit a webpage and scrapes data off that webpage.

You have a describe and then a series of its which hit the webpage.

After this, you would like to include another it that processes the data scraped and tests for validity/integrity, and then spawns a new suite of tests for each data point scraped.

This is currently not supported in Mocha from what I have found, based on the way the pre-require and require event emits that set up the global describe and it functions (and their associated contexts).

I could rather easily override the describe and it functions to manually attach newly generated suites and tests/etc to the correct parent... and then set them back to what they were... but would like to know if there were fundamental reasons this was not (seemingly) purposefully blocked from occurring with the existing codebase.

Comment: I guess you can achieve the same thing with nested describes and befores. Nesting describes in its would not read particularly nice, imo.

Comment: Good point. Hadn't thought of that combination. I just attempted to spawn tests within a before in this manner, and it is placing them under the root suite, rather than in the immediate describe parent... which is why I was thinking of overwriting the describe briefly so that it has the right parent.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because Mocha runs a test suite like this:

1. Finding the tests. When `describe` executes Mocha records the name and executes immediately the callback. When `it` or the hooks (`before`, `beforeEach`, ...) execute Mocha records the test name (for `it` only) and records **for future execution** the callback given.
2. Running the tests. Mocha runs, in the proper order, the callbacks given to `it` and to the hooks. **At this point it is no longer possible to call `describe` or `it` and have them behave properly.** In some questions on SO I've seen some people call `it` from within a callback to `it` and get some sort of behavior but that's just luck. Mocha is not designed for this kind of thing.

There are also structural issues. A `describe` can contain `describe` and `it`, but `it` cannot contain child structures. I guess a `describe` in a `it` could somehow attach to the parent `describe` of the `it`. There's also the issue of tests that are asynchronous: where would a `describe` in them be attached? (By the time the asynchronous code executes the VM has gotten out of the scope of the `it`.) And it is not clear to me that the semantics of the hooks could be maintained.

And reading the comments on the question: no, you're not supposed to put `it` in a `before` hook. However, you can do this:

```
describe("top", function () {

   var test = callSomethingThatReturnsAnArrayOfTestInformation();
   for(var i = 0, test; (test = tests[i]); ++i) {
       it("test " + i, function () {
          // do something with `test`
       });
   }
});
```

In some test suites where I perform one test per file in a directory my `callSomething...` would be `fs.readdirSync(...)`.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time in replying... and thank you for clarifying about the before hook. Question on your code, as it is something I had previously considered, but ran into an issue... is the "callSomething...." call depends on data ran in prior describes... and since it does not return a promise, it is executed immediately by the protractor scheduler (before it runs the other suite's it()'s to determine the data). Do you know a way around this?